# VBA: compile Error: expected function on err.Number

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to make this work and I just can't seem to figure it out. I have this test piece of code that I got from [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/).

```
Sub UsingErr()

On Error GoTo eh

   Dim total As Long
   total = "aa"

Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    Debug.Print "Error number: " & err.Number _
        & " " & err.Description
End Sub
```

This is supposed to help me understand error management but when it's ran I get a: `Compile Error: Expected Function or Variable` on `err.Number`; it specifically highlights `err`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A really good question and answers (well, if you ignore the one with the green checkmark that was accepted for some unknown reason) related to VBA error handling is in the answers to [Can you help me understand more about good practise with VBA Error handling please?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31007009/62576)

Comment: Can you close all Excel files, and open a new one where you put the code in a new module? In general it should be working, I guess.

Comment: Do you have another `Sub` named `err` in your module?

Comment: I don't have any other worksheets open during this; and don't have any modules named err... That I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One minor thing I noticed in your code is the "err" is lower case. When I pasted your code into a blank workbook and ran it, Excel automatically capitalized "Err" in the code. As people mentioned in the comments, this probably means that you have something else open which has a conflicting definition of "err" in it. Try running your code without any other files open.

Comment: I will paste the code to a new blank worksheet and try again.

Comment: I just searched ALL my modules and lo and behold, I had a sub named `err()`. thanks for pointing this out, I feel very dumb.