# How to use IfError GoTo Next function

Tags: vba, excel

Please guide me how can I directly resume to **"s = s + 1"** if i am getting error in the **sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)**. Please guide.

```
For xx = 2 To 15494
xword = Cells(s, m)

If xword <> "" Then
le = Len(xword)
sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)'' If I am getting Error
old_sprd = sprd
's = 1
Star = 1
Do While sprd <> 0

word = Mid(xword, Star, sprd - 1)
xword = Mid(xword, sprd + 1, le)
s = s + 1
Rows(s).Insert
Cells(s, m) = word
sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)
If IsError(sprd) Then sprd = 0
If sprd = 0 Then
s = s + 1
Rows(s).Insert
Cells(s, m) = xword
End If
le = Len(xword)

Loop
End If

s = s + 1 '' My Code supposed to directing divert in This line.
Next
```

Comment: You loop through xx, but there is no use of xx in your code?

Comment: Why don't you use `Instr` instead of `Application.Find`? It will return 0 if the search string isn't found, rather than an error value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Application.Find` use `InStr` (and swap the arguments):

```
sprd = InStr(xword, ",")
```

That does not produce an error, and is more efficient.

In case no match is found, *sprd* will be zero, and so your `Do While` loop will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The following code answers your question as asked:

```
For xx = 2 To 15494
    xword = Cells(s, m)

    If xword <> "" Then
    le = Len(xword)
    On Error GoTo NextLine
    sprd = Application.Find(",", xword) '' If I am getting Error
    On Error GoTo 0
    old_sprd = sprd
    's = 1
    Star = 1
    Do While sprd <> 0

    word = Mid(xword, Star, sprd - 1)
    xword = Mid(xword, sprd + 1, le)
    s = s + 1
    Rows(s).Insert
    Cells(s, m) = word
    sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)
    If IsError(sprd) Then sprd = 0
    If sprd = 0 Then
    s = s + 1
    Rows(s).Insert
    Cells(s, m) = xword
    End If
    le = Len(xword)

    Loop
    End If
NextLine:
    s = s + 1 '' My Code supposed to directing divert in This line.
Next
```

Basically, there are three changes: (1) just before issuing the `Application.Find` command there is a line telling VBA what to do in case of an error `-->` it should go to `NextLine`. `NewLine` is like a bookmark and can be any name you want. You merely need to tell VBA where this bookmark is. That's the second change in your code: (2) adding a line just before `s = s + 1` telling VBA that this is the "bookmark" called `NewLine`. The third change is to tell VBA to only use this "bookmark" if the error occurs on the line `Application.Find`. In all other cases VBA should just pass the error back to you (the user). So, (3) directly after the line `Application.Find` the [error trapping is being turned off again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158901/difference-between-on-error-goto-0-and-on-error-goto-1-vba).

Yet, a better solution would be to use `InStr()` like so:

```
For xx = 2 To 15494
    xword = Cells(s, m)
    If xword <> "" Then
        le = Len(xword)
        If InStr(1, xword, ",", vbTextCompare) Then
            sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)
            old_sprd = sprd
            Star = 1
            Do While sprd <> 0
                word = Mid(xword, Star, sprd - 1)
                xword = Mid(xword, sprd + 1, le)
                s = s + 1
                Rows(s).Insert
                Cells(s, m) = word
                sprd = Application.Find(",", xword)
                If IsError(sprd) Then sprd = 0
                If sprd = 0 Then
                    s = s + 1
                    Rows(s).Insert
                    Cells(s, m) = xword
                End If
                le = Len(xword)
            Loop
        End If
    End If
    s = s + 1 '' My Code supposed to directing divert in This line.
Next xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)?

```
On Error Goto JumpHere:
i = 1 / 0 'throws error
i = 2 'this line is never executed
JumpHere:
i = 1 'code resumes here after error in line 2
```

Hope this helps!