# range.value = range.value Not doing anything (Workbooks(open) issue)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following code to copy some values from an opened csv file to the sheet I'm working on. It works sometimes but will occasionally go through `awb.Sheets("Target").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value = wb.Sheets("csvSheetName").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value` without actually copying any values.

I've stepped through the code and there doesn't see to be any problem. I've tried debugging it: `awb.Sheets("Target").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Select` and `wb.Sheets("csvSheetName").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Select` both grab the correct ranges, `debug.print wb.Sheets("csvSheetName").Range("A1").Value`outputs what it should. `lrow` has value.

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Target").ShowAllData
On Error GoTo -1
Sheet5.Range("A2:A7000").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Target").Range("A2:C7000").Cells.ClearContents

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim awb As Workbook
    Dim myfilename As String


    Set awb = Workbooks("TargetBook")
    myfilename = "www.csvwebsite.com/download.do?query=string"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)

`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    lrow = wb.Sheets("csvSheetName").Cells(Sheets("csvSheetName").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    awb.Sheets("Target").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value = wb.Sheets("csvSheetName").Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    wb.Close
```

The destination range is still blank after that line passes with no error. Usually I can rerun the sub and it will work but this is for a project that's effectively a server backend and is running 24/7. When I tried to debug it yesterday, I wasn't able to get it to work at all. The whole range is usually about 3000 cells total so I don't think it's overloading the memory.

I'm open for other ways to do this but it can't copy-paste as the computer is usually locked when doing this, I found that using the clipboard is finicky in that case. I'm also curious as to why this would only work sometimes... I hate it when something works some of the time.

EDIT: `Set awb = ActiveWorkbook` to `Set awb = Workbooks("TargetBook")` I think that was the reason it didn't work yesterday when I manually stepped through it. The issue was still present after this change, but when I see it, stepping through fixes it.

EDIT2: Increased waiting time after opening workbook to 10 seconds for now.

EDIT3: No issues with either the increased wait time or the change in the accepted answer. Likely something to do with VBA skipping over the object if it wasn't completely loaded.

Comment: What value does `lrow` return when you `Debug.Print`?

Comment: `lrow` returns 1179

Comment: It was originally `set awb = ActiveWorkbook`, I change it to define it specifically and it did the same thing. Tried again without changing it and it's running... I've seen this run for a week straight with no problem, then I'll come in over the week end and it's stuck on this.

Comment: It should be related to the Time taken while opening the Workbook. Increase the Waiting time to 10 secs and run it as a Test. Though that should not be the case as assigning it to a Excel object, as VBA would only go on next step when the workbook has been assigned. Could it be that link sometimes work, and sometimes don't ? or Sheet Name Changes ?

Comment: The sheetname does not change. It's possible that the link doesn't work, but there's error handling to run it again for that reason, I noticed it'll fail to resolve the link once in a while and works the next time.

I added a longer wait time... might take a while to see the problem again. While it _shouldn't_ move on until it's done loading the csv, I've seen that issue before which is why it has the waits. I'll post back in a week or so if it doesn't bug out.

Added an edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159999/11736976

`GoTo -1` clears active error handling while `GoTo 0` disables error handling... in retrospect I'm not sure which is better here - I've needed to use -1 quite often while inside of loops.

Comment: Well `On Error Resume Next` doesn't really handle the error, so `On Error GoTo -1` doesn't make sense I think. You're potentially hiding an error somewhere further along. What happens if you change to `0` instead of `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the second workbook first, and then setting the wb variable to that workbook name.

So this tidbit here

```
Set awb = Workbooks("TargetBook")
myfilename = "www.csvwebsite.com/download.do?query=string"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
```

Try changing it to

```
Set awb = Workbooks("TargetBook")
myfilename = "www.csvwebsite.com/download.do?query=string"
Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
Set wb = Workbooks(myfilename)
```

Comment: This makes sense, could be why the wait was required. I haven't had any issue since increasing the wait time to 10 seconds. Still monitoring it. A few more days of running it I'll add this and bring the wait time down.