# Error handling between higher and lower level procedures

Tags: vba, error-handling, calling-convention

I am running into a problem with a lower level UDF kicking an error up to the highest level subroutine's error handling.  I thought I could fix this with an `On Error GoTo -1`, but the problem still occurs.

According to Microsoft, "without an `On Error GoTo -1` statement, an exception is automatically disabled when a procedure is exited" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement).  Does this mean that when I call a lower level subroutine I am "exiting" a procedure and nullifying the `On Error GoTo -1` statement?

As an example, this is for a subroutine that takes an excel document and combines it with jpg images into a pdf.  The jpg images need to be ordered by the number that ends their file name (i.e. Photomics0).  Occasionally the file name will not have a number at the end of the file name.  I want this to cause the normal error that should occur.

The highest level subroutine has the following error handling:

```
Sub Example()

Do While t = 1

On Error GoTo errorMSG1
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Copyrange)
On Error GoTo -1
'
' more code here & call to other subroutines
'
Exit Sub

Loop

errorMSG1:
    On Error GoTo -1
'
' Code that notifies user that they don't have the excel document open in 
' background and opens it for them
'
End Sub
```

The lowest level UDF (3 levels down) runs into an error with the code:

```
retvalint = CLng(retval)
```

due to the fact that `retval` should be the number at the end of the jpg file name.  With no number `retval` is empty and throws an error causing the code to jump to `errorMSG1`, which I don't want it to do.

I should also say that this always happens when the original error I am trying to trap does not occur.  I have not tested to see if this happens when the original error does occurs.

I have tried throwing `On Error GoTo -1` absolutely everywhere in all levels of my subroutines and functions, with no avail.

Also, on a side note, is this an example of letting errors "bubble up"?

EDIT:
I should also say that I previously tried using `On Error GoTo 0`, but the higher level sub has a large `Do Loop` in it.  I noticed that when the original error I was trying to catch occurred on the >=2 iteration it would spit out the the original `Runtime Error` error.

Comment: Note - that is the VB.Net link. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) is the VBA one.

Comment: Oh, shows how little I know.  Didn't know those were different.

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158901/difference-between-on-error-goto-0-and-on-error-goto-1-vba

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the documentation for this, but I figured it out from testing.

`On Error GoTo 0` stops using the current Error handler.
`On Error GoTo -1` clears the current error.

Here's an example of this:

```
Sub OnErrorTest()
    On Error GoTo myErrHnd
        Err.Raise 42
        myErrorSub
    On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise 44
    Exit Sub

myErrHnd:
    Debug.Print ("Error: " & Err.Number)
    Debug.Print ("Description: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine)
    Resume Next
End Sub

Sub myErrorSub()
    On Error GoTo myOtherErrHnd
    Workbooks("").Close
    Exit Sub

myOtherErrHnd:
    On Error GoTo -1 ' aka Err.Clear
End Sub
```

So to fix the issue you're having, it looks like you need to switch to On Error GoTo 0 after setting the workbook. Normally, errors will bubble up if there is an error handler set in any of their parent functions.