# how to get error detail in VBA programming?

Tags: excel, vba, document

How can I get error details like line number, error message in VBA.
It displays simple message like "Compile error", but does not show detail and line number of error.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get error details like **line number**, **error message** in VBA.

`Compile error` will not let you compile the code and will directly take you to the line which has the error. For other runtime errors, you need to add **line numbers** to your code and then use `ERL` to get the **line number**. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
      Dim i As Long

10    On Error GoTo Whoa

20    i = "Sid"

30    Debug.Print i

Whoa:
40    MsgBox Err.Description & ". Error on line " & Erl
End Sub
```

[image]

**Tip**: I use [MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com/) which helps in inserting/removing line numbers. I think (I am not sure) [rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) also does that.

Comment: I know OP has asked about line number but line numbers... reminds me of good old days of visual basic :). Handy tool though

Answer (score 0):

If your VBA code doesn't contain line numbers, then VBA can not show it.

Purpose of displaying line number is to trace and resolve an error which you can handle using:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

And then Error Handler Block

```
ErrHandler:
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Compile error is different than runtime error.

The compile error will not let the application build and run and the line of code which causes the error is highlighted. On the other hand, runtime error is when the application runs but something unexpected happens which raises an error, a division by zero for exampe.

Once you have sorted out the compile error and the app runs, you can handle rutime errors like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Something()
    On Error GoTo Trap

    'your code here

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also use `Err.Clear` in the Trap.

Comment: Sure you can, but what for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158901/difference-between-on-error-goto-0-and-on-error-goto-1-vba