# On Error Goto 0 not resetting error trapping

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I was under the impression that `On Error GoTo 0` reset error handling.

So why does `On error resume next` not seem to be registering in the following?

```
Sub GetAction()
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

On Error GoTo endbit:
'raise an error
Err.Raise 69
Exit Sub
endbit:
On Error GoTo 0 '<<<reset error handling?

On Error Resume Next
WB.Sheets("x").Columns("D:T").AutoFit
MsgBox "ignored error successfully and resumed next"    

End Sub
```

Comment: @Olle Sjögren There is a lot that is specific to Excel in this post, so I do not think the generic VBA tag is suitable without re-writing to make the question relevant to all other Office products. It is unfair to force a duplicate on a person with a similar problem made specific to say, Powerpoint.

Comment: BTW the more generic question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158901/difference-between-on-error-goto-0-and-on-error-goto-1-vba/14159999#14159999, as cited below.

Comment: @Remou OK, no problem. I just felt that the `On Error GoTo -1` answer was general enough to warrant the [tag:VBA] tag.

Comment: @OlleSjögren I see where you are coming from, and it is a toss-up alright, it just seems to me that this particular question has a lot of Excel in it. If you feel very strongly, I will not fight back :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `On Error GoTo -1` *or* `Err.Clear` to reset error trapping.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158901/difference-between-on-error-goto-0-and-on-error-goto-1-vba/14159999#14159999) I posted a few months ago for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: lol - this link is spot-on - really seems like my question is a duplicate - I've voted to close it with a reference to your other answer

Comment: `Err.Clear` doesn't seem to allow another error handler to be set up. I only get the required results (skipping a few lines of code if there's an error, and then doing something similar again) with `On Error GoTo -1` before setting another `On Error...` - see example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998836/excel-vba-on-error-goto-statement-not-working-inside-for-loop/31543829#31543829